# Getting No goals have been specified for this build in Maven despite puttin in the Goals. Please see the updated POM below. Thanks

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting the following error when I try to run Maven Test on eclipse. Please see below POM.XML

```html
<build>
<plugins>
<!-- surefire plugin -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.19.1</version>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>

<!-- build uploader Linux -->
<suiteXmlFile>src\test\resources\ftp_linux.xml</suiteXmlFile>

</suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>8</source>
<target>8</target>
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac.exe</executable>
</configuration>
</plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>RegressionTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
 
</plugins>
</build>
```

Please see below for the error message. I have also checked the name of the xml file and it is correct. I am not sure why it is displaying as xml file as not a valid one

```html
[WARNING] The requested profile "Test" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "Automation" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project daily-installer: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\daily-installer-automation-master\daily-installer-automation-master-e26d3512b5f2770b8388270ffcc3078e32571d9a\RegressionTests.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:98)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

[image]

Now I am getting the following error

[image]

Here is my updated pom.xml

```html
</plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>RegressionTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
 
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.21.0</version>
 <executions>
<execution>
<id>test</id>
<phase>integration-test</phase>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>
 <suiteXmlFile>
          RegressionTests.xml
 </suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
      </execution>
      </executions>
     </plugin>


</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now working after I added a Goal tag.